# Adding routes in child component React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to add routes inside a child component but somehow it always returns 'NOT FOUND'. This is my code:

App.js:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {};  
    this.handleLogout = this.handleLogout.bind(this); 
  }

  handleLogout(){
    sessionStorage.clear(); 
    window.location.replace('/login'); 
  }

  componentWillMount(){
      if(sessionStorage.getItem('access_token') != null && sessionStorage.getItem('id_token') != null){
          this.setState({loggedIn: true}); 
          console.log(sessionStorage.getItem('id_token')); 
      }
      else{
          this.setState({loggedIn: false}); 
      } 
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div>
            <title>Webshop</title> 
            <NavBar loggedIn={this.state.loggedIn} />
            <Switch>
                    {/*Routes need to be include in App.js otherwise root can't find the paths*/}
                    <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
                    <Route exact path='/categories' component={Categories}/>
                    <Route exact path='/login' component={Login}/>
                    <Route exact path='/register' component={Register}/>

                    {(this.state.loggedIn) ? 
                    <Route exact path='/logout' render={(props) => (<Logout logOutHandler={this.handleLogout} {...props}/>)} />                    
                    : null}

                    {(this.state.loggedIn) ? 
                    <Route exact path='/profile' component={Profile} />
                    : null }

                    <Route render={function(){
                        return (<NotFound/>); 
                    }}/>
                </Switch>
              <Footer/>
          </div>  
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

Profile.js:

```
class Profile extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.id = jwt_decode(sessionStorage.getItem('id_token'))['id'];
        this.getUserData = this.getUserData.bind(this);
        this.getUserData(this.id);
        this.state = {}
        console.log(this.data);   
    } 

    getUserData(_id){
       var user = new User(); 
       var userPromise = user.user_data(_id);
       userPromise.then(
           (val) => { 
               this.setState({email: val.email,
                              firstName: val.firstName,
                              lastName: val.lastName});  
           }
       )        
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <BrowserRouter>
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path='/address' component={UserAddress}/>
                </Switch>
                </BrowserRouter>
                <Container className='content-container'>
                    <Row>
                        <Col md={4}>
                            <Card>
                                <CardBody>
                                    <Row>
                                        <Col md={12}>
                                            <Button className='float-right' color='secondary' size='sm'>
                                                <i className='fa fa-pencil'></i>
                                            </Button>
                                        </Col>
                                        <Col md={12}>
                                            <img className='profileImage'  alt='Profile' src={logo} width={150} height={150}/>
                                            <Table>
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th>Name</th>
                                                        <td>{this.state.firstName}</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th>Surname</th>
                                                        <td>{this.state.lastName}</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th>Email</th>
                                                        <td>{this.state.email}</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <th>Password</th>
                                                        <td>********</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </Table>
                                        </Col>
                                    </Row>
                                </CardBody>
                            </Card>
                        </Col>
                        <Col md={8}>
                            <Card>
                                <CardBody>
                                    <Row>
                                        <Col md={12}>

                                            <Link to='/address'>
                                            <Button className='float-right' size='sm' color='success'>
                                                <i class="fa fa-plus">
                                                </i>
                                            </Button>
                                            </Link>
                                        </Col>
                                        [Here comes a foreach loop fetching all the UserAddress, visualizing them as one card per address, with an remove and edit button]
                                    </Row>
                                </CardBody>
                            </Card>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Container>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

I want to add a route inside Profile.js which redirects to my new component UserAddress but I can't get it to work. I have no errors only returning my 'NOT FOUND' message which is defined in App.js. Could anyone help me out

Comment: You need only one `BrowserRouter` in your app. Wrap your `App` component with `BrowserRouter` like this `<BrowserRouter><App /></BrowserRouter>`. Remove those `BrowserRouter` tags in your `App` component and `Profile` component.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to remove the `exact` from your profile route.

```
<Route path='/profile' component={Profile} />
```

Your child route should start with '/profile', so React will render *Profile.js* and then *UserAddress.js*.

```
<Route exact path='/profile/address' component={UserAddress}/>
```

And you dont need to define another *BrowserRouter* inside the *Profile.js*.

Comment: Will React then also render the Profile.js component? Because I only want it to render the UserAddress component

Comment: Yes, React will render both. Why dont you put the *UserAddress* outside the *Profile*?

Comment: How to do that? I'm a bit new to this component base framework